# Endorsed location for Spark Contributions?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a Spark community (/DataBricks/AmpLab) recognized location for endorsed (/featured ?) spark contributions? Or something along the lines of a CRAN/CPAN for spark?

If not where would one look for spark contributions - or is it simply searching github.com for spark related projects (which will end up finding many limbo/dead projects) ?

An area of particular interest would be machine learning algorithms. The mllib/graphx are purposefully kept small and lean - to maintain a small codebase.

However there should be a means to allow expansion of the available ML libraries for spark outside of the Spark distribution proper.  Maybe we will not end up with 4000 libraries like for R. But "dozens" or maybe low hundreds?  Seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is http://spark-packages.org/. It's linked from http://spark.apache.org/ (Libraries → External Package Index).